# Rails - disable option in select (based on the condition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, helper

I have select:

```
= f.select(:category_id, @categories, :html_options => {:class => 'select_box'}, {:disabled => true if category.id == 18})
```

The piece of code above obviously returns an error, but how to disable an option according by `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't tested this but in your controller could you not do

```
@checkvar = @category.id == 18 ? true : false
```

then in the view

```
f.select(:category_id, @categories, :html_options => {:class => 'select_box'}, {:disabled => @checkvar})
```

or in the model write a function to test

```
def disable_select 
    if self.id == 18
        true
    else 
       false
    end
end
```

then in the view

```
f.select(:category_id, @categories, :html_options => {:class => 'select_box'}, {:disabled => @category.disable_select})
```

Comment: This won't work with HTML5. Because it'll simply add disabled attribute with no value and that is still valid in HTML5. So, u need a helper method which returns either a empty hash or hash with disabled option set

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.select :status, STATUSES.map{|s| [s.titleize, s]}, { disabled: DISABLED_STATUSES.map{|s| [s.titleize, s]} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this recently and used the following solution:

```
#view
= f.select(:category_id, @filtered_categories, :html_options => {:class => 'select_box'}

#controller
@filtered_categories = Category.all.select do |category|
  [logic here]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For `select_tag`, we can do:

```
<%= select_tag "sample", options_for_select(
    [['A', 'a'], ['B', 'b'], ['C', 'c']]),
    {class: 'form-control', disabled: data.present? == false ? true : false}
%>
```