# Rails bootstrap and disabled button on condition true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my controller, I have

```
  def show
       current_scheduled_messages = 5 #(just for example)
       @checkvar = current_scheduled_messages > 3 ? true : false
  end
```

In view

```
<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sms-scheduling-modal" href="#", disabled = @checkvar> Schedule a text message</a>
```

I want to disable button if @checkvar will be true. I am unable to find right syntax. Please tell me right syntax to do this.
Reference : [Rails - disable option in select (based on the condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364293/rails-disable-option-in-select-based-on-the-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="btn btn-default <%= @checkvar ? 'disabled' : '' %>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sms-scheduling-modal" href="#"> Schedule a text message</a>
```

or

```
<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sms-scheduling-modal" href="#" disabled="<%= @checkvar ? 'disabled' : '' %>"> Schedule a text message</a>
```

Comment: @Adt, Its because you are using `a` tag as `bootstrap` **button**. So, the `disabled` class then disable the button.

Comment: How can i do same with javascript

Comment: `$("a").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
    <%= f.submit "Button text", class: 'btn btn-primary', :disabled       
    => @intance_variable.your_boolean_attribute? %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sms-scheduling-modal" href="#",  <%= @checkvar ? 'disabled' : '' %>> Schedule a text message</a>
```

Just encapsulate the @checkvar using embedded ruby: "<%= ... %>"

Comment: Its disabling button even if value is false

Comment: oh wait it's exactly the same as the below answer :S

Comment: How can i do same with javascript